# Displaying Search Results from Lucene with new version Lucene (6.0)

Tags: servlets, lucene, document

I am trying to created a servlet that uses Lucene. How would I display the results from indexSearcher as a list of document names or path names? It used to be in the older versions, you could just do searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc) to get a document which you can get then get names or pathnames from with document.get(string). The new version has gotten rid of getDocument and I am not really sure how to change scoreDocs or topDocs into documents so I can fetch relevant information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`searcher.doc(int scoreDoc)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#doc-int-). This method returns the `Document` instance where you can call [`get`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#get-java.lang.String-) to obtain the stored value.